# How to generate absent report of all employee between two specific date in laravel?

Tags: laravel-4

You have only attendance table with `id`, `name`, `date`.

EmployeeId int primary key

EmployeeName nvarchar(50)

Date

Comment: What you have tried so far and where your stuck.

Comment: i want to generate a absent report of all employee of a company between two specific date from attendance table with eid, ename, attendaceDate.